# Failed to RSA decrypt with java

Tags: java, php, encryption, rsa

My password is encrypted with RSA in an android app. On the server side, I need to decrypt it., What I have is a .pem file, and the php code for decrypting:

```
 function privatekey_decodeing($crypttext, $fileName, $fromjs = FALSE)
    {
        $key_content = file_get_contents( $fileName );
        $prikeyid = openssl_get_privatekey( $key_content, "1234" );
        $crypttext = str_replace(' ', '+', $crypttext);
        $crypttext = base64_decode( $crypttext );
        $padding = $fromjs ? OPENSSL_NO_PADDING : OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING;
        if( openssl_private_decrypt( $crypttext, $sourcestr, $prikeyid, $padding ) )
        {
            return $fromjs ? rtrim( strrev( $sourcestr ), "/0" ) : "" . $sourcestr;
        }
        return;
    }
```

the fileName is frivatekey file(.pem file)
Now I need to use java to decrypt it. I have tried some methods, all have failed. Here is what I have tried:

1. using the .pem file to generate a .der key file
2. reading the .der file to get the privateKey
3. using the byte[] read from .der file to generate keyfile

   ```
   public static PrivateKey generatePrivateKey(byte[] key)
       throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
       KeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key);
       KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
       return keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
   }
   ```
4. decrypt my password

   ```
   public static byte[] decrypt(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] data)
       throws Exception {
       Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHOM, DEFAULT_PROVIDER);
       ci.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
       return ci.doFinal(data);
   }
   ```

But it does not work, and I do not know where is going wrong.
In the php code I see `$prikeyid = openssl_get_privatekey( $key_content, "1234" );`
But I don't know what does the "1234" means. Does it mean using "1234" to encrypt the keyfile? Is this the reason the decrypt failed?

Comment: Yes, the 1234 is a passphrase that was used to encrypt the key itself.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser,and the modifying to my question(I sorry for my poor English, and not checking the question) , and do you know how can I use "1234" to decrypt the keyfile in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$padding = $fromjs ? OPENSSL_NO_PADDING : OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING;`

These are both bad options:

- Unpadded RSA [is insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3925/24405)
- PKCS1 padding (which is also the default padding mode) is [vulnerable to chosen-ciphertext attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/can-you-explain-bleichenbachers-cca-attack-on-pkcs1-v1-5); thus it's also insecure

Please don't implement RSA yourself. You're going to make your application incredibly insecure.

Recommended reading:

- [Cryptographic right answers](https://gist.github.com/tqbf/be58d2d39690c3b366ad)
- [The original cryptographic right answers](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html)
- [Recommended PHP cryptography libraries](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide)
- [Crypto Fails](http://www.cryptofails.com/archive)
- [How to safely implement cryptography in any application](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-safely-implement-cryptography-in-any-application) (covers Java and PHP)

Comment: Thanks for such professional answer, Digesting them is not an easy thing for me , but I'll try to get it.

Comment: Easy mode: libsodium-jni for the client + libsodium-php on the server.